# How to find this integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1-x^4}\arctan{\frac{x-x^5}{1+x^6}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, closed-form

Find the integral value
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}
{x \over 1 - x^{4}}\,\arctan\left(x - x^{5} \over 1 + x^{6}\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

My good friends gave me this problem, and I can't solve it. Using computer I found closed form 
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}\left[{x \over 1 - x^{4}}\,
\arctan\left(x - x^{5} \over 1 + x^{6}\right)\right]\,{\rm d}x
={\pi \over 8}\,
\left[\left(1 + \,\sqrt{\,5\,}\, \over 2\right)^{3} - {\ln\left(5\right) \over 2}\right]
$$

Comment: [Hint](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html).

Comment: Hello,@Lucian? How use this it? Thank you

Comment: With friends like that

Comment: You can use the "hint" from Lucian to show that
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1-x^4}\left( \arctan x - \arctan x^5 \right) \,\mathrm{d}x\,,
$$
but I do not see how this helps you a lot..

Comment: The Maple code $$evalf(Int(x*arctan((-x^5+x)/(x^6+1))/(-x^4+1), x = 0 .. 1), 30)  $$ outputs $ 0.250901930278428691790985083059$.

Comment: @user64494,Hello,I have closed form,Thank you

Comment: Your forget a log in your closed form, should be $\dfrac{\pi}{8}\left(\color{red}{3\log}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\dfrac{\log{5}}{2}\right)$. For a derivation, see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/364989/59379). It is the $F(1)$ there.

Comment: @achillehui: thanks for digging that one up.  I recall the admiration I had for O.L.'s solution; glad I had not yet attempted much of anything.

Comment: @achillehui I performed a  numerical check $\left(~\approx 0.250902~\right)$ and it agrees with your proposed answer. It has becoming common that the OP doesn't answers important points as your comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{1}{2n+4k+3}\right)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341302/how-can-i-find-sum-limits-n-0-infty-left-frac-1n2n1-sum-limits)

Comment: @anorton I think this is another case when an answer to question A uses answer to question B, but they are not really duplicates. In fact, I wish the answer by O.L. wasn't as terse as it is, because the transformation isn't obvious.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Between N3b's comment above and achille hui's comment, I thought it was obvious.  But that's why I don't have the power to unilaterally close questions... :)

Answer (score 2):

Using **Lucian**'s suggestion, rewrite the integral as
$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{x\left(\arctan x-\arctan x^5\right)dx}{1-x^4}dx.$$
Its calculation using complex-analytic methods is essentially [one of my very first posts on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364989/73025).

I briefly sketch the idea so that your question could be considered as answered. For more details, see the link above.

1. Integrate by parts using that $\int\frac{xdx}{1-x^4}=\frac14\ln\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}$ and rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as
   \begin{align*}
   \mathcal{I}
   =\frac14\int_0^1\frac{(1+x^2)(1-3x^2+x^4)}{x^8-x^6+x^4-x^2+1}\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx.
   \end{align*}
2. Use the symmetry w.r.t. the change of variable $x\rightarrow\frac1x$ and parity to further rewrite this as
   $$\mathcal{I}
   =\Re\int_{\mathbb{R}+i0} f(z)\,dz,\qquad f(z)=\frac{1}{16}\frac{(1+z^2)(1-3z^2+z^4)}{z^8-z^6+z^4-z^2+1}\ln\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right).$$
3. Pull the contour of integration to $i\infty$. The residues at simple poles are easily computable and the $2\pi$-jump on the logarithmic branch cut $[i,i\infty)$ produces an integral of a rational function.